# Malformed response from Paypal IPN instead of VERIFIED or INVALID

Tags: paypal-ipn

Since July 1st we started receiving malformed IPN response from paypal with an odd string at the bottom of the IPN that is neither VERIFIED or INVALID but something like a non binary sign. This happens randomicly and both for payments related IPNs and for preapprovals.

If we try to resend the IPN from the paypal IPN history sometimes they get verified from paypal at the first time, sometime we have to retry more than once. Never happened before and nothing changed on our side in the ipn verification script that is old but work fine with the most part of the IPNs.

We've checked the endpoint and it is correct:
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

We've tried to resend some of those malformed IPNs and after one or more retry they comes out correctly VERIFIED.

When we try to get those affected IPN validated in the LIVE production, what we get is a bad request because of this odd string at the bottom of the affected IPNs instead of the VERIFIED or INVALID response:

‹      TŽK‚0„ïüŠ•»,M<Œ$¨ÄÔÇb›@‚ûÐøïmáäe’ÙùvgÉ¦¸æ¬mJ8±s
Í=««â-bU²#bÁŠ5Ù')by‰iDzû)é%ÞØÁŽ’Ò2.à&_NKpGŒtJ|ÃæŽþQÞGd¦­r:­>Fj0r²ÀA¯ØžŒôÛçåF“²à&!µ±| é4`¨›ƒ,mþzø3ú  ÿÿ Î[óâ

Comment: Same here.
We have exactly the same problem with every few payments.
Example: 

    ‹      TЋK‚0„пьЉ•»,ЏM<Њ$ЁДФЗb›@‚ыРшпmбдe’ЩщvgЙ¦ёж¬mJ8±s
Н=««в-bUІ#bБЉ5Щ')by‰iDzы)й%ЮШБЋ’Т2.а&_NKpGЊtJ|ГжЋюQЮGd¦­r:­>Fj0rІАAЇШћЊфЫзеF“Іа&!µ±| й4`Ё›ѓ,mюzш3ъ  яя О[ув

Comment: I've the same problem, as you mentioned it  occurs sometimes not ever.

Comment: We've opened a ticket to paypal support on July 2nd but we've not received any feedback at the moment. Just keep waiting, if anyone in the thread have some news, please share it.

We've initially thinked about the newer endpoint that should be used:
https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr instead of https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr (that we're using at the moment, but rethinking on it, this shouldn't be involved at all because the malformed IPN arrives BEFORE we send it back to the endpoint for verification.

Comment: We've just switched to latest IPN script available in PayPal's GitHub - will let you know if it solves the problem (i don't think that it will...)

Comment: Hi mr.d. thank you for your feedback, yes please let me know if it solves the problem  but I think it won't too because it seems definitely something wrongly sent on the paypal side (can you please give me the link to the more recent ipn script on github just for a comparison with the script that we're using at the moment? Thanks).

Comment: Sure: https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples
Our backend is running php 7.2

Comment: Definitely, it's not related to the IPN listener. We just got a BAD response again, using their latest example code.

Comment: Hi mr.d. consider that the IPN listener, if well configured, just send back for verification the SAME thing that paypal send to the listener so the issue is certainly BEFORE the postback. In the interlocutory answer they've given yesterday, they admit the issue, no solutions yet. Will keep all of you informed as soon we'll get any news. Please do the same. All in the same boat at the moment.

Comment: It affects PDT too. Same string, except for unprintable characters probably being stripped in your post.

Comment: Can we programatically request PayPal to send the malformed IPN again, or is logging into `Instant Payment Notification (IPN) history` and manually searching for a txn id the only way to get them re-sent?

Comment: As far as I know, re-send from IPN history is the only way.

Comment: Today is the 17th of July, for the last 72 hours, there are no malformed responses from PayPal at our side.

Comment: Hi mr.d today, 17th of July someone on the paypal community forum added a comment saying that the issue was fixed, keep waiting the confirmation myself to post it as a solution. Some one knows if changing the ipn endpoint from https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr to the newer https://ipnpb.paypal.com is mandatory or not? And what about the "/cgi-bin/webscr" part of the endpoint url? Must be added or not?

Answer (score 3):

Finally, just got a "human" answer from Paypal and immediately share it here for those affected by this issue with some workaround:

"Thanks for contacting PayPal Merchant Technical Support. We are so sorry for the late response to you. I acknowledged that you got IPN error HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request issue. Please kindly note that this is a known issue in PayPal at the moment. Our relevant department is working on it.

...

In addition, you can also do as follows for the workaround to confirm this transaction.

1. Call GetTransactionDetails API to find this transaction details.
   https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/
2. Go to your PayPal account to check transaction details.
3. Download report to find this payment.
4. Check notification email sent to your email box *** about this payment.

But we'll keep you posted for the update information of this IPN 400 Bad Request problem."

So, it's not a real solution at the moment but just some workaround available for payments (those workarounds, for example, doesn't work for preapprovals where you still have not a payment). 
We even asked why if it is a known issue, there's nothing on it on the paypal-status website where the "notification" product is market as green and in good health. Will update when we have a real solution.

Comment: Can we programatically request PayPal to send the malformed IPN again, or is logging into `Instant Payment Notification (IPN) history` and manually searching for a txn id the only way to get them re-sent?

Comment: Hi Codemonkey, as far as I know, the only way to have an IPN resent is to force this from the IPN history dashboard from your paypal account. Paypal does resend IPN automatically just in one case: if your server doesn't respond 200 OK at the moment they make the first attempt. A tricky workaround might be to check the message and, if it is something else than "VERIFIED", force your server to respond other than 200OK to make Paypal resend the IPN but all these are just odd ways to make something that doesn't work anymore work, not solutions.
We just have to wait the paypal team to fix this :(

Answer (score 3):

The binary chunk is a compressed html-answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

I can confirm the random behavior and sending the exact verify-request later again we get a correct verify-answer.

Sorry for not adding this info as comment (< 50 reputation).

Answer (score 1):

Received today a message from Paypal Merchant Technical Support saying that the issue has now been fixed. Some of you reported yesterday that, accordingly, were correctly receiving IPNs with no malformed text, please keep monitored for a few days before accept this as a solution.

Cheers, Fil.

Comment: After some days, I can report that we've no more reveived malformed IPN from paypal in the last 10 days. It might be considered fixed.